# Joomla and Shopping Cart without HTTPS

Tags: joomla, https, virtuemart

I have a new client whose website is having all kinds of problems (I'm just coming into the situation now).  It's a Joomla site with a VirtueMart shopping cart, but when I'm using the shopping cart, it doesn't appear to be using https.  I'm a novice when it comes to shopping carts, but I would think this is a critical issue.  Isn't this really, really bad?!?  Or is it a feature of Joomla and VirtueMart?

Comment: When dealing with payments online, it's always best to use HTTPS as I assume you know it's more secure. There could be a few reason why it hasn't been used on your clients' site, such as: Good SSL certificates are quite expensive (especially if you're on a budget), it decreases site performance, the person who developed it might not have any idea about SSL Certificates. Either way, I would recommend you get your client to purchase a SSL Certificate.

Comment: Hi Lodder. Any reason you didnt put this as answer? I'd +1 it

Comment: @WooDzu - Not sure lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with payments online, it's always best to use HTTPS as I assume you know it's more secure. There could be a few reason why it hasn't been used on your clients' site, such as: Good SSL certificates are quite expensive (especially if you're on a budget), it decreases site performance, the person who developed it might not have any idea about SSL Certificates. Either way, I would recommend you get your client to purchase a SSL Certificate